# How can I turn a string into a calculation?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that is `"1+2"`

How can I make this string become 1+2, and equal three, in Javascript?

Comment: you can use Javascript's eval() function. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Small note concerning eval: be careful about what you put into. And its also really slow.

Comment: Without eval: `"1+2".match(/\d+/g).map(Number).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just eval that string in JS:

```js
console.log(eval("1+2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp):

`eval("1+2") = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `Function` as well.

```js
console.log(Function("return " + "1+2")());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem but the simplest is likely this:

```
input = '1+2'
output = eval(input)
```

Hope this helps.